How to remove duplicates without changing the position of the segment
i have a requirement to remove the duplicate ITEM segments without checking its sub node and its values, and without alerting its position, XSLT i used is currently checking exact ITEM segment match, so its not removing and placing the ITEM field at last.
if multiple ITEM has same N11 and AR value then we can consider it as duplicate and we need to keep anyone occurrence, but if ITEM has Subnode exists then we need to consider that particular ITEM only, by removing other ITEMs
Input sample
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<D02X001>
    <DOC BEGIN="1">
        <DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <NAM>DC40</NAM>
        </DC40>
        <BXYH SEGMENT="1">
            <LDAT>date</LDAT>
            <UDAT>date1</UDAT>
            <BXYI SEGMENT="1">
                <TNR>123453</TNR>
                <ORT>1000</ORT>
                <ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                </ITEM>
                <ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                    <subnode>
                        <field1> 13</field1>
                    </subnode>
                </ITEM>
                <ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                </ITEM>
                <ITEMNEW SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                    <PQC>NU</PQC>
                    <QTY>3456</QTY>
                    <NUM/>
                    <ASCD/>
                </ITEMNEW>
            </BXYI>
            <BXYI SEGMENT="1">
                <TNR>123453</TNR>
                <ORT>1000</ORT>
                <ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                </ITEM>
                <ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                    <subnode>
                        <field1> 13</field1>
                    </subnode>
                </ITEM>
                <ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                </ITEM>
                <ITEMNEW SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                    <PQC>NU</PQC>
                    <QTY>3456</QTY>
                    <NUM/>
                    <ASCD/>
                </ITEMNEW>
            </BXYI>
        </BXYH>
    </DOC>
</D02X001>

output sample
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<D02X001>
    <DOC BEGIN="1">
        <DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <NAM>DC40</NAM>
        </DC40>
        <BXYH SEGMENT="1">
            <LDAT>date</LDAT>
            <UDAT>date1</UDAT>
            <BXYI SEGMENT="1">
                <TNR>123453</TNR>
                <ORT>1000</ORT>         
                <ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                    <subnode>
                        <field1> 13</field1>
                    </subnode>
                </ITEM>     
                <ITEMNEW SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                    <PQC>NU</PQC>
                    <QTY>3456</QTY>
                    <NUM/>
                    <ASCD/>
                </ITEMNEW>
            </BXYI>
            <BXYI SEGMENT="1">
                <TNR>123453</TNR>
                <ORT>1000</ORT>     
                <ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                    <subnode>
                        <field1> 13</field1>
                    </subnode>
                </ITEM>     
                <ITEMNEW SEGMENT="1">
                    <N11>6789</N11>
                    <AR>03</AR>
                    <PQC>NU</PQC>
                    <QTY>3456</QTY>
                    <NUM/>
                    <ASCD/>
                </ITEMNEW>
            </BXYI>
        </BXYH>
    </DOC>
</D02X001>

XSLT I used
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
   <xsl:key name="item-by-N11-AR" match="BXYI/ITEM" composite="yes" use="N11, AR"/>

  <xsl:template match="BXYI/ITEM[not(key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR))[subnode])][not(. is key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR))[1])]"/>
  <xsl:template match="BXYI/ITEM[key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR))[subnode]][not(. is key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR))[subnode][1])]"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>



</xsl:stylesheet>



Can you please specify in detail when to ITEM elements are to be considered duplicates? As for not changing the position, are all ITEM elements at the same level? Can there be nested ITEM elements?

Also, of the duplicated ITEMs, which is the one you want to output, the first, the last, some in between?

if multiple ITEM has same N11 and AR value then we can consider it as duplicate, we can keep anyone occurrence, but if ITEM has Subnode exists then we need to consider that particular ITEM only, by removing other ITEMs

All ITEM and ITEMNEW are at the same level under it main header BXYH

You can try it with a composite key and then additionally check for subnode and empty templates for the duplicates you don't want to output e.g.
  <xsl:key name="item-by-N11-AR" match="ITEM" composite="yes" use="N11, AR"/>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM[not(key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR))[subnode])][not(. is key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR))[1])]"/>
  <xsl:template match="ITEM[key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR))[subnode]][not(. is key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR))[subnode][1])]"/>

  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

Online fiddle.
This currently eliminates ITEM duplicates at any level of the document.
To restrict the elimination of duplicates to ITEM children of BXYI and to work with multiple BXYI elements change the code to use e.g.
  <xsl:key name="item-by-N11-AR" match="BXYI/ITEM" composite="yes" use="N11, AR"/>

  <xsl:template match="BXYI/ITEM[not(key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR))[subnode])][not(. is key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR), ..)[1])]"/>
  <xsl:template match="BXYI/ITEM[key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR))[subnode]][not(. is key('item-by-N11-AR', (N11, AR), ..)[subnode][1])]"/>


  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>


i have same multiple case of BXYI segment, which its eliminating only first level, i have changed code same as you said, now modified input and output, please have a look

@PaddT, I have edited the second sample to apply the key function only in the context of the parent .. which is your BXZI elements; I think this solves the problem for your edit to the question's input sample.

Hi @martin, code you given is exactly working, but i found one case, where its removing ITEM as same ITEM exist in another BXYI/ITEM,  I have posted this as new question, request you to have a look
